# Product page filter

Tags: filter, product-page, related-products

[image]

(link to webshop)
https://sanitairkamer.nl/mondiaz-aivy-badmeubel-120cm-chai-met-wastafel-solid-surface-urban-midden-1-kraangat-en-spiegelkast-sk77173.html

I'd like to re-create the product page like you see in the picture. So the filters on the right section does not funtion als custom option, but more like a button to be reffered to another product page of the same product but with different size or color or any of the available options you see on the right side.

Is this possible?